# Does any version of NHibernate exist which has support for .Net Core?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, asp.net-core, fluent-nhibernate

I am testing an asp .net core sample project with NHibernate, but I've been unable to make it work. Does any version of NHibernate have support for .Net Core?

Comment: Question is about asking compatibility of a library, which is better suited asking the developers of the tool rather than users on SO. https://github.com/nhibernate for official github repo, ask or read the issues there, as the developers of the tool are the right persons to address, not community. Update: Its located here https://nhibernate.jira.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: The support has been added: http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2018/03/26/nhibernate-now-supports-net-core-2-0/

Comment: NHibernate 5.1.0+ can target .NetStandard 2.0 or .NetCoreApp 2.0 - View Dependencies - https://www.nuget.org/packages/NHibernate/5.1.0

Answer (score 4):

This was actually discussed on the fluent-nhibernate google group this morning

https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/504

Answer (score 2):

Not yet. You can follow the progress on https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3807